# Why is the code not exiting the while loop even though the condition to exit is valid?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why is the code not exiting the while loop even though the condition to exit is valid? I can't see any problem with that

```
from pytube import YouTube

url = input("Enter the link: ")

yt = YouTube(url)

while True:
    option= input("Select option: Audio 128kbps = 1, Audio 50kbps = 2, Audio 70kbps = 3, Audio 160kbps = 4: ")


#itag="140"         itag="249"        itag="250"        itag="251"
      
    if option ==1 or option ==2 or option ==3 or option ==4:
          break
    print(option)

if option==1:
    stream= yt.streams.get_by_itag(140)
elif option==2:
    stream= yt.streams.get_by_itag(249)
elif option==3:
    stream= yt.streams.get_by_itag(250)
elif option==4:
    stream= yt.streams.get_by_itag(251)


stream.download()
```

Comment: `input()` returns a string.  Therefore `option` is a string, and it cannot equal integer `1` etc.

Comment: Compare to `"1"`, `"2`, etc. There's no need to convert `option` to an integer when you are just comparing them to hard-coded values.

Comment: I've been enlightened thanks

Comment: You tagged "Python 2.7" here.  In Python 2.7, the `input` function would return an integer here, not a string.  Are you actually using Python 3?

Comment: Yes I'm using python3, I've already solved my problem